# How do you review changes of MR that depends on other MR being merged?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-flow, merge-request

I am starting to work with other developers on a project where I have mostly worked alone up until now.

Our repo is hosted on GitLab and I am trying to figure out how to setup a simple git workflow for the team.

We have a `master` branch with the code that goes to production and I would like team members to work on feature branches that then get merged onto master.

For now, when one wants to resolve an Issue, it creates a Merge Request with a branch and pushes code to it. When it's ready they ask for review, and if the review passes I merge the feature branch to `master`. So far, so good.

The problem I can't solve right now is: if a team member wants to continue working on another issue that depends on a previous issue being merged, how can I review the code of the dependent merge request?

In this case, we would have a `master` branch, a `issue-1` branch based on `master` and an `issue-2` branch based on `issue-1`.

If the target of both merge requests is `master`, when reviewing the changes of `issue-2` I would also have to sift through the changes of `issue-1`, which I should have already reviewed separately on `issue-1` merge request.

Is it possible to keep `master` as the target branch for both MRs but use `issue-1` as the base for the diffs of `issue-2`?

I know there's a Merge dependency premium feature, but I don't think it solves this particular problem.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> In this case, we would have a master branch, a issue-1 branch based on master and an issue-2 branch based on issue-1.

A branch to be submitted as a merge request *cannot* be based on another branch to be submitted as a merge request.

The person working on `issue-2` can certainly branch it from `issue-1` in order not to have to copy those commits, but then `issue-2` must later be *rebased* onto `master`, and this must be done with exquisite timing — namely, after `issue-1` has been merged to `master` but before final submission of `issue-2` for approval.

It would be better, however, not to do that. If `issue-2` truly depends on `issue-1` they should never have been different branches / merge requests in the first place. In general, merge request branches need ideally to be "orthogonal", i.e. they should do completely independent things to `master`.

Comment: > If issue-2 truly depends on issue-1 they should never have been different branches / merge requests in the first place.
Ok, so what if I have a sequence of issues, some can be done in parallel, but most require the previous issue to be completed. Should I have one single merge request? How would I review their code separately from issue to issue?